# scala: how to explicitly ask for an implicit conversion?

Tags: scala

Is there a way in scala to explicitly ask for an implicit conversion, or do I *have* to always define functions for that purpose?

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
...
def toScalaCollections( v:Any ) : Any = {
  v match {
    case v2:java.lang.Map[Any] => v2.implicitly[ scala.collection.Map[Any] ]
    case v2:java.lang.Iterable[Any] => v2.implicitly[ scala.collection.Iterable[Any] ]
    ...
  } 
}
```

Is there an operator like implicitly in the language?

NB. clearly I can work around like by defining

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
...
def toScalaCollections( v:Any ) : Any = {
  v match {
    case v2:java.lang.Map[Any] => toScalaMap(v2)
    case v2:java.lang.Iterable[Any] => toScalaList(v2)
    ...
  } 
}
```

my point is, is it possible to not to have to do this?

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your two snippets? Have you looked at [Scala's implicit conversions](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html)?

Comment: In the second one, I need to define a functions, toScalaMap and toScalaList that cause the implicit conversion. Can't I just ask for an implicit conversion. I can't rely on the assignment type -- the function returns Any. Similarly, I could force an implicit conversion by assigning to a typed variable. This also seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, you MUST specify in some way that you need these collections to be of the Scala collection types.  Since your function returns type `Any`, Scala has no way to understand your intention is to return Scala typed collections.  This is the tersest way I know to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
def toScalaCollections( v:Any ) : Any = {
  v match {
    case v2:java.util.Map[Any, Any] => v2:scala.collection.mutable.Map[Any, Any]
    case v2:java.lang.Iterable[Any] => v2:Iterable[Any]
  }
}
```

Note that I used Scala's mutable map because the immutable one is not supported by `JavaConversions`.

Comment: What going on here. In general you can't write (expr):type to perform any explicit type cast. At least, if class A extends B, then val x=a:B fails to compile (which is fine to trigger the implicit rules -- I'm just confused about the :type syntax here). Can this notation be used only for downcasts (or where the compiler can prove the cast will succeed at runtime)?

Comment: I don't the know the details very well. I believe it works any time you have a value which is of some type `A` which is implicitly convertible to another type `B`. So it's not a downcast per se.

Answer (score 10):

Do not use `JavaConversions` at all. It is exactly the example of why sometimes implicit conversions are bad. It is very difficult to control when implicit conversion should be done because Scala collections framework is very complex and all collections have multitude of methods. `JavaConversions` really should be deprecated - this is a widely accepted opinion in Scala community.

Use `JavaConverters` instead. This API provides neat methods `asScala` and `asJava` which perform the conversion just when you need it:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val sm = Map[String, String]("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d")
val jm: java.util.Map[String, String] = sm.asJava
val sm2: Map[String, String] = jm.asScala
assert(sm == sm2)
```